# Change Position of div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to Change Positioning of HTML div Via Javascript in my existing Script

Currently This My Existing Javascript is generating in front end.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse affix" id="SubMenu" style="top: 72px;">
```

But i want to make positioning to `top:8px`

JavaScript is as Below.

```
// Sub-navbar affix on scroll
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($('#SubMenu').length) {
    $('#SubMenu').affix({
        offset: {

            top: function() {
                return $('#SubMenu').parent().offset().top - $('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight();
            },
        }
    }).css('top', $('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight());
    // Update values on window resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        theTop = $('#SubMenu').parent().offset().top - $('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight();
        $('#SubMenu').data('bs.affix').options.offset = {
            top: theTop
        };
    });

    $('#SubMenu').on('affixed.bs.affix', function() {
        $('a.navbar-brand.scrollTop span').text($('#destination-the-title').val());
    });
    $('#SubMenu').on('affixed-top.bs.affix', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('a.navbar-brand.scrollTop span').text('');
        }, 600)
    });
}
```

Comment: where is your html...

Comment: This is original HTML <div class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top" id="SubMenu">   but after using JS i am getting <div class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top" id="SubMenu" style="top:74px;">

Comment: `document.getElementById("SubMenu").style.top=8px` wouldn't work?

Comment: Well I Want to Edit Existing Javascript I have. Any Solutions Where i can edit in Above JS ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery just use the following line of code.

`$("#SubMenu").css("top","8px");`

To be more precise 
instead if this part

`.css('top', $('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight());`

add `.css("top","8px");`

Comment: Sooraj , Thank you, But Which Line of  Code can i Remove From Above Jquery and Where Should I Place it?? I am New to jquery So, I dont know where to Edit these.